# Which is better to handle SQLite between Exposed and Anko in Kotlin?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I know that both  Exposed and Anko can operate SQLite easily, could you tell me which one is more better when I develope an Android App?

Comment: What is Exposed?

Comment: @PankajKumar this is [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed)

Comment: @HelloCW I can tell to you that `Anko` is great than `Exposed`. `Exposed` cause troubles and dificult implementation. I tried both and my preference is `Anko`

Comment: Room from Google is also an option for easily using the SQLite database on Android.

Comment: Android does not use JDBC for SQLite. Exposed is not for Android framework.

Comment: Thanks! What is "Room from Google" ?

Comment: [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)

Comment: If you want to use SQLite you should go for Room https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/

Answer (score 4):

Use the framework you are most comfortable with. I tried [`Exposed`](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) once and it was ok for what I've used it. [`jooq`](https://www.jooq.org/) might also be a valid alternative instead.

Reading the documentation of both, [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) and [Anko](https://www.kotlinresources.com/library/anko/), I would stick to either one of those.
Regarding which of those, I just found an issue asking the very same question (even though just as a second or third question):

- https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/484

Some other resources I found regarding Room and Anko:

- [Stress-free SQLite with Anko](https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/anko-sqlite-database/): the [comment regarding Anko vs Room](https://www.kotlindevelopment.com/anko-sqlite-database/#comment-3743284248) is also insightful:

  > Anko SQLite provides a nice API to manage your data persistence layer but you still have do the heavy lifting by yourself. While Room is more like a framework. Generates databases from annotated classes for you, provides observable queries and has a really nice testing support. Also works well with Android Architecture Components.

Ah... and don't get me wrong. Exposed is ok too, I am still using it ;-) But if you are familiar with both, you may also have your preferred choice already. If you don't know any, you can try both and choose the one where you grasp the documentation more quickly or you feel more comfortable sooner.